# How to use custom ACF fields in Wordpress permalink?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I am currently building a website using Wordpress as CMS.

We offer recurring workshops. I have registered this as a custom post type. As most workshops feature the same name I would like to create a permalink which shows the date of the workshop like so: /workshop/*day*/*month*/*year*/best-workshop-ever.

Can I do so by using a custom field created by Advanced Custom Fields?
Or are there other options to achieve this?

Comment: This is just a regex setup thing - nothing to do with ACF. https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/ is the kind of approach it looks like you're going for. If you want a custom function, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/113068/use-date-in-the-url-of-custom-post-type is a start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any ACF field in URL thank to the plugin:
https://github.com/athlan/wordpress-custom-fields-permalink-plugin/

Functionality i also extended by:
https://github.com/athlan/acf-permalink/

You can also calculate your own fields on-the-fly based on fields (like parse date and extract three separate custom post fields on-the-fly for permalink purpose) using [`generate_dynamic_metadata`](https://github.com/athlan/wordpress-custom-fields-permalink-plugin/wiki/Plugin-hooks#generate_dynamic_metadata) filter. [Example here](https://github.com/athlan/wordpress-custom-fields-permalink-plugin/wiki/FAQ#how-to-generate-calculated-dynamic-custom-post-meta-keys-and-values).